# jQuery-Prototype no conflict and correct syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax

I want to know how I need to write the line `$j('#'+divRes).html()=datos;` in order to work properly in a jquery-protype environment. I obtain the error: **invalid assignment left-hand side**

```
function tx_oriconvocatorias_formPost_init(divRes) {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'eID=ori_convocatorias_formPost',
            success: function(datos){
                $j('#'+divRes).html()=datos;
            },
        });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change it to  `$j('#'+divRes).html(datos);`

In jQuery, to read the html, use `var str = $('#id').html()` and to assign, `.html('[html string]')`

Comment: Thanks. Is the first time I work with jQuery and I thought that maybe the problem was something else.

Comment: So, can I write something like: .html('<p>'+datos+'</p>')

Comment: Yeah absolutely (presuming datos is `html` or `text` in itself).

Answer (score 3):

`.html(datos)` is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with prototype, you can't assign to that.  You want to do this:

```
$j('#'+divRes).html(datos);
```

Answer (score 2):

To set the html using jQuery the command is,

```
$j('#'+divRes).html(datos);
```

.html() returns the current html, which you are trying to set, which causes the error

Comment: Thanks for the final explanation.